# High model performance degradation on use of cosine as distance function in machine learning compare to Euclidean

Tags: metric-spaces, neural-networks, euclidean-domain

I was working on classification of images based on similarity using machine learning. I am experimenting with both Euclidean and cosine distance. I found that as the no of classes grows, cosine as distance measure performance degrades quickly. For example, when I had 25 class there is a difference of just 3-5% in accuracy between them (63% for Euclidean vs 59% with Cosine). However, when I had 40 classes then this difference grows to 41 % (92 % with Euclidean vs 51% with cosine). What could be the reason for such behaviour/degradation. Is there any paper/resource where I can look for explanation.

Comment: There are a number of details you need to elaborate on. Euclidean distance is typically a metric for regression, but I assume you are using it as a distance function for two probability tensors (or vectors if the batch size is 1?) Why not the standard cross-entropy loss?

Also are you getting a similar training loss before testing with each loss function? The overfitting issue may be worse for one loss than the other which is worth investigating.

Comment: Also this post might be better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, or even signal processing stack exchange for computer vision questions.

Comment: Also see here:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222585/what-are-the-impacts-of-choosing-different-loss-functions-in-classification-to-a

Comment: I am using feature vector comparison of 1 image with n images. So that I can compare the embedding generated by CNN network.  Loss is also very high now compare to last time on the same line with accuracy. I wanted to know the mathematical perspective behind this, so I posted here. Now, I will ask data science folks as well.